# When importing data into a table in SQL, what is the duplicate table name with the Suffix "$"

Tags: sql, import

So I exported two tables in their entirety out of SQL (2005) into an excel file.  During the import wizard to import the tables, on the screen presenting the tables to import it showed 4 tables.

Two which were duplicate names with the small difference of having the suffix "$" on the end.  I chose to import all 4 and it went through.

Are the tables with the "$" suffix metadata or some other information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $ is what you see when you are working with Worksheets in Excel. If you want to import into the same table, get rid of the automagic naming and import into the table itself.

Want proof? Export tables to an Excel spreadsheet. Reimport without removing the $. Compare data between the tables. You will not have all of your constraints on the "$" tables and the data types might be off, but the data will be identical.

Comment: My case is I don't have access to directly import from table to table.  Therefore, if I use the table (without the $) during the import, will I retain the constraints and datatypes?